# Find the intersection of two lists in tcl

Tags: tcl

Is there a command that will allow me to get the intersection (members that apear in both lists) of two lists?

For example, if the lists are:

`a b c d h` and `c e f g h`

the result should be `c h`

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything in regular Tcl, but TclX has an intersection function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming what you really have is a set (a list with unique elements), you can use tcllib:

[::struct::set intersect  ? set1... ?](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_set.html)

```
package require Tcl 8.0
package require struct::set

set list1 {a b c d h}
set list2 {c e f g h}
::struct::set intersect $list1 $list2
> c h
```

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a command, but typically the way I do this is *cache elements during construction* of one or more of the lists, to save time.  For example, given the following:

```
foreach x {a b c d h} {
    lappend list_x $x
}

foreach y {c e f g h} {
    lappend list_y $y
}
```

I would add:

```
foreach x {a b c d h} {
    lappend list_x $x
    set cache($x) 1
}

foreach y {c e f g h} {
    lappend list_y $y
    if {[info exists cache($y)]} {
        lappend list_xy $y
    }
}

puts $list_xy
```

Output:

```
c h
```

Comment: From 8.5 onwards, that should be pretty fast (if put in a procedure).

Answer (score 2):

```
package require Tcl 8.5
set a {1 2 3 4 5}
set b {3 4 5 6 7}
set intersect [list]

foreach elem $a {
    if {$elem in $b} {
        lappend intersect $elem
    }
}
```