# Keeping common elements from two list in tcl and place them in a result list

Tags: list, duplicates, tcl

I have two list of different length containing integers.
There are now duplicates within a list.
There are duplicates when looking at both lists.
eg

```
set ListA [list 3 4 9 1 2 10 6 ]
set ListeB [list 34 43 9 12 2 10 61 88 23 48]
```

Is there an effektive quick way to create a new list which only contains the numbers existing in both original list? In this case: [ 9 2 10 ]

I do not want to use nested loops since the list may be large. I first thought of sorting them and then compare them element by element. That however only works if both list are of the same length....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the intersection of two lists in tcl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027197/find-the-intersection-of-two-lists-in-tcl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12027197/1578604) and the [documentation here](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_set.html). This worked for Tcl 8.0 and still works on 8.5 (and I'm pretty sure 8.6 as well).

```
% package require Tcl
% package require struct::set

% set ListA [list 3 4 9 1 2 10 6 ]
% set ListeB [list 34 43 9 12 2 10 61 88 23 48]
% ::struct::set intersect $ListA $ListeB
9 2 10
```